# ionic 2 current location doesn't return any thing and it times out on Android device

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location, ionic2

ionic 2 current location doesn't return any positions when i fire up the app and then aks the user switch on the location. Once the user swtiches the GPS on and clicks the retry button to get the position of the user the getcurrent user location doent return any positions. However when the gps is on and i fire up the every thing works.

I also check to see if the location is enabled first and then try to get the current location. any idea why would this happen ?

```
        Diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then( bool =>{
            if( bool == false ){
              console.log("location is disbaled")
            }
            else{

                Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {

                  this.usersLocation = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude, 
                            lng: position.coords.longitude
                        };

                  console.log('user location', this.usersLocation);                                                

                }).catch((error) => {

                    console.log('falling back to deafult user location', 
                    this.usersLocation);                                                

                });                                       
            }
        });
```

Comment: try to put an error callback to `isLocationEnabled().then()`

Comment: The isLocationEnabled works and return true once the GPS is on, however getCurrentPosition defaults to the catch section with no Error. This is the option variable that i have :                                                                  let options = {
                    timeout: 10000,
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }

Comment: I just double checked and i get this error :  "Code 3: Timeout expired" .

Comment: try inserting this call `Diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then` inside `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: Thanks, but its still the same. maybe i should reinitialize the gps on ionic side ? how would i do that ?